How does this single printf() line affect my result?
I was in the middle of building an AVL Tree until this odd thing happened. When I comment this printf() on line 81, my resulting balance factor shows a random(?) number when its actual BF is 0. But, when I uncomment the printf() line, the resulting BF shows 0. How is this happening?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
    
    int num;
    struct data *left;
    struct data *right;
    int bf;
    
};

struct data *root = NULL;

struct data *create_node(int num){
    
    struct data *new_node = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    new_node->num = num;
    new_node->left = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;
    
    return new_node;
    
}

int bf_left(struct data *bot, int depth){
    
    if(bot == NULL){
        return depth - 1;
    }
    int temp = bf_left(bot->left, depth + 1);
    int temp2 = bf_left(bot->right, depth + 1);
    
    if(temp > temp2){
        return temp;
    } else if(temp <= temp2){
        return temp2;
    }
    
}

int bf_right(struct data *bot, int depth){
    
    if(bot == NULL){
        return depth - 1;
    }
    int temp = bf_right(bot->left, depth + 1);
    int temp2 = bf_right(bot->right, depth + 1);
    
    if(temp > temp2){
        return temp;
    } else if(temp <= temp2){
        return temp2;
    }
    
}

int bf_finder(struct data *bot){
    
    int left = bf_left(bot->left, 1);
    int right = bf_right(bot->right, 1);
    return left - right;
    
}

struct data *insert(struct data *bot, int num){
    
    if(bot == NULL){
        if(root == NULL){
            root = create_node(num);
            bot = root;
        } else{
            return create_node(num);
        }
    } else if(num < bot->num){
        bot->left = insert(bot->left, num);
    } else if(num > bot->num){
        bot->right = insert(bot->right, num);
    }
    
//  printf("%d\n", bot->num);
    bot->bf = bf_finder(bot);
    
}

void print_all(struct data *bot){
    
    if(bot != NULL){
        print_all(bot->left);
        printf("%d. bf: %d\n", bot->num, bot->bf);
        print_all(bot->right);
    }
    
}

int main(){
    
    insert(root, 10);
    insert(root, 9);
    insert(root, 11);
    insert(root, 12);
    
    print_all(root);
    
    return 0;
    
}

I'm expecting my code to show an actual BF of 0 if it's actually 0 with or without this printf() line because I thought there's no way a single printf() can affect this much, but if I'm wrong, I wanna know what is actually happening.

Do you really want to be ignoring what your insert() function returns?

In fact it does not return anything on most of the paths. Your compiler should be warning you about this.

i just realized something that in my create_node(), i didn't assign the new_node->bf to 0 or anything. That's why they output random number instead of 0, also because in my code, i didn't assign the leaf's BF value, only their parent.

Short answer: UB; long answer: Undefined Behavior.
